# When to use singular or plural when the phase is something with somethings?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms, singular

Consider these examples:

```
bicycle with wheels
bicycles with wheels
burger with fries
burgers with fries
words with definitions
word with definitions
word with definition
```

Which ones of these are correct? I have seen the more common one is `word with definitions`. However, it sounds correct when using `burgers with fries` when you are buying 2 meals. Are there any general rules of thumb when using these clauses? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using singular or plural nouns is purely based on whether you have one of something, or multiple of something.

If you have multiple burgers, say so.  If you have a single burger, say so.

This even applies with proper names.  You would say "Quarter Pounders with Cheese", not "Quarter Pounder with Cheeses" or something like that.